# PHPStorm xdebug guzzle fails to stop at breakpoint if SAME domain

Tags: debugging, phpunit, phpstorm, xdebug, guzzle

This is a strange one... I using PHPStorm and I AM able to nicely debug phpunit tests on a remote vagrant VM. I can walk through, set breakpoints, etc. I am considering the use of HttpGuzzle for testing REST api's. I AM able to run AND debug a unit test for example when using Laravel's call, ie, `$this->call('GET', 'https://api.github.com/feeds');` to make a request, however when I use Guzzle's get `$client->get('https://api.github.com/feeds')`, it acts like it has stopped at a breakpoint in some other file. PHPStorm says it is "Running...". It will eventually timeout with no other error messages.

If I am NOT remote debugging this test, it successfully completes the test!!!

So it seems to misbehave only when debugging a Guzzle request!

Answer (score 3):

- Set your debug settigns in PHPStorm **"Max. simultaneous connections" higher than 1**
- Set you xdebug settings in Vagrant: **xdebug.remote_connect_back = 1** and **xdebug.remote_autostart = 1**

In my case this was the problem